# How to track how many times a event is sent?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm building a code with jest and puppeteer to check if an event is sent only once when the page is loaded.

I'm having issues to build a code with puppeteer to return a message if the same event is sent again.

```
const eventTest = async (viewEndpoint) => {
        await Promise.race([
            page.goto(url),
            await page.waitForResponse(viewEndpoint)
            .then(await page.waitForResponse(viewEndpoint, 10000))
            .then(console.log("Event loaded more than once"))       
        ])
    }
```

The code above is what i've tried till now. `viewEndPoit` is the event endpoint of a given url. First I navigate to the page, then I'm using `page.waitForResponse` with the event endpoint and if everything is right i'm using `then` to do it again. And then load the message if the event occurs again.

It's not working, it always return `console.log`, even though the event loads only one time.

When a home page loads,for example, an event called home is sent. I can check it on the devtools network tab. My goal is to return the console.log if the event appears twice on the network tab.

Comment: Start by not mixing async/await with then/catch, thing will become clearer from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way would be to simply use the function `page.waitForResponse` twice and then use the function inside your `Promise.race` afterwards.

**Code Sample**

```js
const waitForEventTwice = async () => {
  try {
    await page.waitForResponse(viewEndpoint, { timeout: 10000 });
    await page.waitForResponse(viewEndpoint, { timeout: 10000 });
    console.log('Yes it happened twice.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('No, it didn't, a timeout error happened instead');
    // You might want to "throw err" here depending on your use case
  }
}

await Promise.race([
    page.goto(url),
    waitForEventTwice(),     
]);
```

---

A more sophisticated approach would be to count up the number of times the event has been fired and `resolve` accordingly. This makes sure there will be no missed events due to not listening for events for a split-second.

```js
const waitForEventTwice = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let counter = 0;
  page.on('response', function listener(response) {
    if (response.url() === '...') { // test if the response is the response you are looking for
      counter += 1;
      if (counter === 2) {
        // ...
        resolve(); // it happened
      }
    }
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    server.removeListener('response', listener);
    // it did not happen
    // ...
    reject(); // or resolve() alternatively depending on your use case
  }, 2000);
});

await Promise.race([
    page.goto(url),
    waitForEventTwice(),     
]);
```